# How to use ubuntu-touch as a desktop?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

My platform: Google nexus 4, ubuntu-touch/ stable.
Is there any instruction of how to combine with external keyboard and monitor to use the nexus 4 ubuntu-touch as a desktop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parts necessary to make Ubuntu Touch work as a desktop are not finished, and have not landed in the Nexus 4 images, so this isn't yet possible with the shipping image.